# How to update 'src' attributes of multiple images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following source:

```
  <body>
    <div class="slideshow_top">
      <img class="slideshow_image" src="img/cycle/putritos.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow_mid">
      <img class="slideshow_image" src="img/cycle/stage.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="slideshow_bot">
      <img class="slideshow_image" src="img/cycle/marketing.jpg">
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
```

Assuming I have three generated new `src` values such as:

```
var src1="img/cycle/newimage1.jpg
var src2="img/cycle/newimage2.jpg
var src3="img/cycle/newimage3.jpg
```

How can I change the source values of the already existing images? I'm unsure because I know the surrounding divs of the images are uniquely named, but the class of the images themselves are shared. Is it still possible to update each source attribute with Javascript given this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like part of your question has to do with selecting images only if they are a child of a `slideshow_top/mid/bot` `div` element. There's a few ways to do this...

In jQuery, you could do this:

```
$('.slideshow_top img').attr('src',src1);
$('.slideshow_min img').attr('src',src2);
//etc.
```

That's just a simple Sizzle CSS-style selector. You can also use jQuery's `.children()` method, if you want:

```
$('.slideshow_top').children('img').attr('src',src1);
```

In plain old JavaScript it's a little more wordy, but you can still do it:

```
var slideShowTop = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow_top'),
    slideShowTopImage = slideShowTop[0].getElementsByTagName('IMG');

slideShowTopImage[0].setAttribute('src',src1);

//etc.
```

Note though, that `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported in version of IE less than 9, so you'll have to write your own little function to, say, loop through all elements by tag name and filter them by `className`, etc. jQuery might be the way to go on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Try

[.each( function(index, Element) )](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-functionindex--Element)

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

```
//create array of images 
var arrSrc = ['img/cycle/newimage1.jpg','mg/cycle/newimage2.jpg','img/cycle/newimage3.jpg'];
$('.slideshow_bot .slideshow_image').each(function(i, el){ //to loop through images 
    el.prop('src',arrSrc[i]); //set image here
});
```

[.prop( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var new_images = $.map([1,2,3], function(x) { return "newimage" + x + ".jpg"; })
$("img").each(function(i, x) { x.src = new_images[i]; })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var src_array=["img/cycle/newimage1.jpg","img/cycle/newimage2.jpg","img/cycle/newimage3.jpg"]

$(".slideshow_image").each(function(index){
$(this).attr("src",src_array[index])
})
```